# Restriction on non-SDK interfaces

Tags: android, interface, sdk

Hi present I am getting a warning from the play store that I am using these non-SDK interfaces in my app. they gave a few ways to find out errors and to make it solve. 
later when I used the lint tool I can not see any errors regarding these apps.So how can I go to my code and solve my problem. I mean how can I go to code and shift to any other public API.

1. Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V
2. Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe;
3. Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z